# Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativePath parameter

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, relative-path

I am struggling with using the SharepointAPI to download a file from a company url like this

```
sharepoint_url = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/personalsite"
sharepoint_path = "/sites/mysite/Shared/General/Data/Datafile.txt"
```

but keep getting this error:

> office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: ('-2147024809, System.ArgumentException', "serverRelativeUrl\r\nParameter name: Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativePath parameter.", "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https‍://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/personalsite/_api/Web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('https:%2F%2Fmysite.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Fpersonalsite')?$select=ServerRelativePath")

So I dont know what to do , I am using it in Python

Answer (score 1):

Try using the same site for the API and for the file:

```
sharepoint_url = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite"
sharepoint_path = "/sites/mysite/Shared/General/Data/Datafile.txt"
```